# Google App Engine Modular Project Structure

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

There is much talk about the microservices architecture in Google App Engine. In fact, the documentation seems to compel the developer to lean towards building apps in microservices. The perspective of a project seems to be either a 'monolithic' mess or a well-organised microservices project. However, it is [debatable](http://www.ptone.com/dablog/2015/07/microservices-may-be-the-new-premature-optimization/) that perhaps microservices is not the suitable approach during early phases of a project.

With this said, is there a recommended approach to project structure for building a AE project in a modular way? Assuming that we would want to organise our project to consist of the following characteristics:

- A service is organised as a module
- Modules can easily access shared resources (datastore, task queue, memcache)
- Modules provide their own API
- Modules can be testable
- Modules conform to the session / authentication services

My assumed solution is the following:

```
project/
  app.yaml
  main.py
  requirements.txt
  libs/
  module1/
    datastore/
    endpoints/
    tests/
  module2/
    datastore/
    endpoints/
    tests/
  module3/
    datastore/
    endpoints/
    tests/
  auth_module/
    tests/
    endpoints/
  sessions_module/
    tests/
    endpoints/
  datastore_module/
    tests/
    endpoints/
  taskqueue_module/
    tests/
    endpoints/
```

Comment: Flask Blueprints provide a nice way to break up your web app like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your organisation can work. However in recommend you to stronger differentiate module and library. Auth, session, datastore, task queue can be use by different microservice. Put them in a dedicated sub directory, like `packages`.

About the early phase, I agree. In theory, 1 microservice = 1 team, and at the beginning, teams aren't staffed or the budget isn't present. However, the trap is to accumulate technical debt and to split in monolith is too huge... Experience is the key